# ~/Library/PDF Services gone in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, pdf, printing

Hey Y'all - I'm using the ~/Library/PDF Services directory to inject an item into the PDF Workflow sub-menu (Print dialog box) in OS-X/Leopard.

I got an indication that the PDF Services directory is *gone* in Snow Leopard. Does anyone know the correct way to hook into the Print dialog's PDF Workflow going forward?

Thanks!

[Note: I got some time on an S-Leo system the other day. find made it pretty clear that the user ~/Library/PDF Services is not to be found someplace else. The system /Library/PDF Services is still in place. I changed my app to just make the directory if it is missing, and the S-Leo print dialog box finds it just fine. So the soln is to just make the directory if it is not already there.]

Comment: Voted to close because Snow Leopard is under Apple NDA. You can ask Snow Leopard questions at Apple's dev forums: http://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: @Graham You may have signed an NDA, but you have no evidence the questioner did.

Comment: Let's I asked this question. There would be nothing wrong with my conduct, since I did not sign any NDA with Apple. So, how do you know jeff7091, whoever he/she is, signed one?

Comment: Because Apple have a blanket NDA on Snow Leopard. The only people who have copies without being under non-disclosure are people with illegitimate copies. Either way, this question evinces naughty behaviour ;-).

Comment: I did NOT sign an NDA. I was working on the international space station, and another astronaut had a copy. He wanted to try my app on his SnoLeo. Because we were in space, the NDA did not apply.